# Trying to update table in SQL using visual studio and getting this error 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update

```
string Query = "UPDATE dbo.acca_Problems SET UserID = @UserID, Name = @Name, Description = @Description WHERE Name = @Name, Description = @Description";
                                      
using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query))
{
    Command.Connection = Connection;

    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", 0);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ProblemName.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", ProblemDesc.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SolutionLanguage", ProblemLang.SelectedValue);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DifficultyLevel", ProblemDiff.SelectedValue);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleInput", ProblemIn.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleOutput", ProblemOut.Text);
    // Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProblemFile", ProblemData);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTimeUpdated", time);

    Connection.Open();
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Connection.Close();
}
```

I want to update all the values but I'm trying to test out description and name first. Receiving that error on `Command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Even with the corrections offered in answers so far, this makes no sense. Simplify to one column - `SET Name = @Name WHERE Name = @Name` - what exactly do you expect to change there? The only rows you're affecting are the rows which already have the value you're trying to set.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Side point #2: do not cache connection objects. Create them when you need them, dispose with `using`

Comment: @Larnu please don't advocate Joel's advice without also mentioning [Can we start using AddWithValue](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/) - Joel still hasn't  updated his blog post to make it clear what databases it's a problem for. Banging on like it's a universal evil is irresponsible; better to just promote Dan's balanced and informed advice than Joel's rant

Comment: @GeorgeFlores I'd say `WHERE UserId = @UserId` would be more typical, or perhaps if you wanted to make sure no one else has updated the record in the time you've had it then `SET Name = @NewName WHERE Id = @Id and Name = @OldName`...  . The set of statements in the WHERE clause need to be a logical truth, so like `where a = 1 and (b = 2 or c=3)` not a comma separated list of truths. Always use parentheses when mixing AND and OR, by the way; `name = John and (age = 20 or city = Chicago)` is very different to `(name = John and age = 20) or city = Chicago`

Comment: @CaiusJard, there are 2 articles to read there, and the OP is using SQL Server, where it is a known issue. Unless you are saying Dan's article is "wrong" too?

Comment: No, my issue is that Joel says "add with value is terrible, never ever use it" - that's bad advice because it isn't universally true, yet he makes out that it is; SQL Server isn't mentioned at all in Joel's article. Dan says "add with value causes problems in sql server, use ..". If you want to make a "avoid AWV in SQLS" point (valid), I recommend Dan's post over Joel's. You should take it as incumbent upon you to present a balanced picture; link to "AWV is fine for MySQL" too

Answer (score 2):

In your `WHERE` clause, you need to use `AND` to join the parts together instead of a comma.

Like this:
`WHERE Name = @Name AND Description = @Description`

Comment: This would achieve nothing though. What's the point in updating the value to be the value it is?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a comma where the operator `AND` should be. So the string Query should be:

```
string Query = "UPDATE dbo.acca_Problems SET UserID = @UserID, Name =@Name, Description=@Description where Name = @Name AND Description=@Description";
```

Comment: That would make it able to execute indeed, but raised the question... why is OP updating `Name` and `Description`? Seems not necessary (because the rows would already have that balue because of the `WHERE`)

Comment: @Cleptus, understood. I think the OP was just trying to troubleshoot the syntax before writing a full update statement that would probably make more sense to all of us.